# Exporting data from Dynamics 365 and send it to FTP service

Tags: dynamics-365

We have Dynamics 365 online and I want to perform followings,

- Export data from 3 or more entities into excel, I need different column names in excel sheet.
- Send data to a FTP
- This will happen everyday once

I am new to dynamics 365, I did some research but nothing concerete is coming up to start with, I tried to create a report in dynamics 365 but it only let me create report based on 2 entities. I am not sure what other possibilities I have.

I am happy to use Microsoft Flow or some online SISS cloud or azure functions, anything

Comment: There is exact example how to export data from Dynamics 365 using C# and Dynamics SDK: https://dreamingincrm.com/2016/11/10/export-to-excel-using-dynamics-365-sdk/
Does it help?